# What is the Basic difference between Rpc and Rmi?

Tags: web-services, rmi

I want to understand the difference between RPC and RMI?
Also what RPC webservice and document or jax ws webservice.. ?what are all differences?

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the difference between calling a procedure in a non-object-oriented way and calling a method on an object in an object-oriented way

The rest of your question is too broad to answer here.